# Mysql one to many join return all records

Tags: mysql

Coming up with the correct title for this was a bit challenging.

So I've got a user profile table, a music genres table, and a genre_profiles table for the one to many association.  Below I've got a group_concat that returns all the genreName for a profile, but there is a problem.  I want to return all the genres for a profile even when I'm filtering for a specific genre like genreID 15.

```
SELECT *, group_concat(cast(g.genreName as char) SEPARATOR ', ') as genreName 
FROM profiles p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre_profiles gpro ON gpro.profileID = p.profileID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN genres g ON g.genreID = gpro.genreID
WHERE gpro.genreID = '15' 
GROUP BY p.profileID
```

How do I go about filtering my query for a genreID leaving the genreNames associated with a profile intact?  Should I do a subquery for all the profiles with a profileID of 15 and then get all the genre data from that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this solves my problem.

```
SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( g.genreName AS CHAR ) SEPARATOR  ', ' ) AS genreName
FROM profiles p
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre_profiles gpro ON gpro.profileID = p.profileID
LEFT OUTER JOIN genres g ON g.genreID = gpro.genreID
WHERE gpro.isInfluence =  '0'
AND p.profileID IN 
(SELECT gp.profileID
FROM genre_profiles gp
WHERE genreID = 10)
GROUP BY p.profileID
```

It works in all my test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to move the `AND gpro.genreID = '15'` from the `JOIN` to the `WHERE` (though I'm not 100% sure that I'm reading you right).

Comment: sorry I pasted it wrong as I deleted some unnecessary query code.